# Need help with Peak USB Hardware

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know which package is best suited for writing custom application that can Send and Receive CAN messages using Peak USB hardware.
From the search I could find libpcan & Socket_CAN as two options. Out of this two:
1.I am not sure how to install libpcan with melodic(I am not sure whether even it is supported).
2.I am not able to find any documentation on Socket_CAN APIs which I can use for reference.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309186/need-help-with-peak-usb-hardware./) by [RohanA](https://answers.ros.org/users/38339/rohana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally used Linux PCAN Basic APIs.

---

Originally posted by [RohanA](https://answers.ros.org/users/38339/rohana/) with karma: 16 on 2018-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0